# disable and enable events in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to disable and enable a div in my codes - i found off() and on() function for disable event and they're works fine but the problem is that i can not use the handler which i defined before . for example :

this is the code which disable listner on load

```
function disableEvent ()
{
    $("body").ready(function(e) 
    {
        $("#part *").attr("disabled","true").off("click");
        $("#sgmnt *").attr("disabled","true").off("click");
        $("#subSgmnt *").attr("disabled","true").off("click");
    });
}
```

and this is the code enable listner

```
function enableElmnt ( id )
{   
    p="#"+id+" *";
    alert(id);

    $("body").ready(function(e) {
    $(p).attr("disabled","false").on("click",false);
    });
}
```

and this is the handler code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".partElements").not("#part19").not("#part20").not("#part21").click( function(){
    $(".partElements").not("#part19").not("#part20").not("#part21").css("background-color","#FFF");
    $(".partElements").not("#part19").not("#part20").not("#part21").css("color","#000");
    $(this).css("background-color","#000");
    $(this).css("color","#FFF");
    selectDiv=$(this).attr("id");
        loadLists("2",selectDiv);
     });
});
```

and the html code

```
 <div id="part">
       <div class="partElements" id="part1"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part2"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part3"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part4"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part5"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part6"></div>

       <div class="partElements" id="part7"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part8"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part9"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part10"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part11"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part12"></div>

       <div class="partElements" id="part13"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part14"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part15"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part16"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part17"></div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part18"></div>

       <div class="partElements" id="part19">edit</div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part20">ddelete</div>
       <div class="partElements" id="part21">modify</div>
     </div>
```

Comment: how does your html look like? selecting * its very expensive, have you tried adding a class to the container and using it as condition?

Comment: thanks for yout attention , i add the html code to question

Comment: who is calling the enable and disable events? also a jsfiddle would be useful to understand the problem :)

Comment: thnak you , events disabled at the load by body , and when ajax response the UI the events should be avaible , function loadlist () call the enableElmnt()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem i see in your code is the order in which the different functions are called.
 Firstly, I think you don't need a $(document).ready in your enableElmt function and then reconsider the other pieces of code.

When $(document) is ready, you want to disable all divs. Then, at a certain point, when an ajax call returns, you want to enable your divs and do something else.

So second error should be the $(document).ready (the third part of your code), managing the click on your divs (while those divs are still disabled).

So, in order i would do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(disableElmt());
```

putting away the $(document).ready() inside the function.

Then, put away the $(document).ready() inside the EnableElmt and make it called by the ajax response.

At the end of the enableElmt you can then call the code that manages the clicks on the divs (otherwise still disabled)

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you , this is not work- i hide the elements and when i need i show them , this work Temporarily

Answer (score 0):

My approach would always bind the handler. I would change the handler code so it could decide if an action needs to be done, e.g.:

```
$("SELECTOR").on("click", function() {
    if (!$(this).prop("disabled")) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

The handler is always called, but there is only an action, if the clicked element isn't disabled.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your attention  , it's not work, looks likes the problem is in handler not in disable and enable - i don't know :(